# Make textview vertically scrollable

Tags: android, textview, scrollable

How to make multiple textview vertically scrollable in a certain different portions of the screen ?

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView"
>     android:layout_width="200dp"
>     android:layout_height="200dp"
>     android:src="@drawable/girl1" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="200dp"
>     android:layout_height="200dp"
>     android:id="@+id/textview"
>     android:maxLines="8"
>     android:scrollbars="vertical"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
>     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"></TextView> </RelativeLayout>
>
>
>
> TextView intro;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_meet_our_team);
>
>     TextView txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
>     String text="I like programming in Android. This tip shows you how to make a TextView scrollable in Android.";
>     txtview.setText(text);
>     intro.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
> } }
> ```

I am getting following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.cepl_pc.trial.MeetOurTeam.onCreate
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies on line `intro.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

You haven't assigned any id to TextView intro , replace it with your txtView.
Also,you have `android:maxLines = "8"` and your text string is not long enough to get a scroll view, use below code you will see the scrolling effect.

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/girl1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:maxLines = "3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"></TextView>
```

In java,

```
TextView txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String text="I like programming in Android. This tip shows you how to make a TextView scrollable in Android.";
    txtview.setText(text);
    txtview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: What will I do if I wanto have 3 imageviews and 3 textviews and want them to scroll.

Comment: In that case I just you to use listview for multiple rows, your row will have imageView and textview , there will be no restriction of views ,you will be able to add as much as imageViews & textViews you want one below another.:)

Answer (score 2):

**You can even**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want all of your layout to scroll.Set ScrollView as your root layout and set fillview port to true.like this:

```
<Scroll View
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"/>
.
.
//rest of your xml code.
.
.
<ScrollView/>
```

if this works let me know in comments section.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get around to it would be to enclose it in `ScrollView` in your .xml file as following.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/girl1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"></TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare textView

```
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

in a method add following code

```
textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```